# how to prove $\exp(t) \ge \sum\limits_{k=0}^{2n-1} \frac{t^k}{k!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives, taylor-expansion

How to prove the inequality, 
$\quad \exp(t) \ge \sum\limits_{k=0}^{2n-1} \frac{t^k}{k!}$, $ $ whenever $t \in \mathbb R , n \in \mathbb N^+$.

When $t\ge 0$, it can be prove easily by the Taylor expansion $\exp(t) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^k}{k!}$,
but when $t<0$, I can't prove it. Need help. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: Using Mathematical Induction to prove.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Please take moment to give [this posting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34067) a read to learn how to ask a good question.

Comment: By Taylor's formula with integral remainder, $$
{\rm e}^t  - \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{2n - 1} {\frac{{t^k }}{{k!}}}  = \frac{{t^{2n} }}{{(2n - 1)!}}\int_0^1 {{\rm e}^{ts} (1 - s)^{2n - 1} {\rm d}s}  \ge 0
$$ for all $t\in\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$$ f_n(t)= \exp(t)-\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2n-1} \frac{t^k}{k!}. $$
Now one can use Mathematical Induction to prove $f_n(t)\ge 0$ for $t\le0$.
If $n=1$, it is easy to show $f_1(t)\ge0$ for $t\le0$. Now suppose $f_{n}(t)\ge0$ for for $t\le0$. Then
$$ f_{n+1}''(t)= \exp(t)-\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2n-1} \frac{t^k}{k!}=f_n(t)\ge0, t\le0 $$
which implies that $f'_{n+1}(t)$ is increasing. So for $t\le0$,
$$ f_{n+1}'(t)\le f_{n+1}'(0)=0$$
which implies that $f_{n+1}(t)$ is decreasing. So for $t\le0$,
$$ f_{n+1}(t)\ge f_{n+1}(0)=0. $$
Thus by MI, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$,
$$ f_{n}(t)\ge 0$$
for $t\le0$.

Answer (score 3):

The direct proof is possible. Consider the function $$g(t)=e^{-t}\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}{t^k\over k!}$$  We get $$ g'(t)=-e^{-t}{t^{2n-1}\over (2n-1)!}$$ Therefore $g'(t)>0$ for $t<0$ and $g'(t)<0$ for $t>0.$ Thus the maximal value of $g(t)$ is attained   at $t=0.$ Hence $g(t)<g(0)=1$ for $t\neq 0.$ Finally $$\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}{t^k\over k!}=e^tg(t)< e^t,\  t\neq 0$$

Similarly we can prove that $$e^t<\sum_{k=0}^{2n}{t^k\over k!}, \quad t<0 \quad (*)$$ Indeed for $h(t)=\displaystyle e^{-t}\sum_{k=0}^{2n}{t^k\over k!}$ we have $\displaystyle h'(t)=-e^{-t}{t^{2n}\over (2n)!}.$ Therefore the function $h$ is strictly decreasing on $(-\infty,0].$  Hence $h(t)>h(0)=1$ for $t<0,$ i.e. $(*)$ holds.